# Contagem regressiva usando tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou tentando bolar um programa no tkinter para fazer uma contagem regressiva.

Não consigo entender porque não consigo pegar a Entry e transforma-la em um inteiro.(Como este é apenas um teste, fiz usando o português mesmo)

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()

inicio = Entry(root)
#adicionei esta linha abaixo
print(inicio.get())
sec = int(inicio.get())

def tick():
    global sec
    if sec == 0:
        time['text'] = 'TEMPO ESGOTADO'
    else:
        sec = sec - 1
        time['text'] = sec
        time.after(1000, tick)

label = Label(root, text="Quanto tempo você tem para realizar suas tarefas?")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
inicio.grid(row=1, column=0)
time = Label(root, fg='green')
time.grid(row=2, column=0)
Button(root, fg='blue', text='Start', command=tick).grid(row=3, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Foi printado apenas um espaço em branco, como pode ver.

Comment: Jovem, qual é o problema que ocorre?

Comment: line 6, in <module>
    sec = int(inicio.get())
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Comment: Tem como você printar o valor que está tentando converter e postá-lo aqui?

Comment: Nao estou tentando converter nada ainda, o programa nem abre... fica só no terminal

Comment: Orra, jovem. Isso **`sec = int(inicio.get())`** é uma tentativa de conversão. Faça `print(inicio.get())` e poste o que for mostrado na tela.

Comment: perdão pela ignorancia... sou iniciante. Adicionei a linha e o terminal continua dando a mesma mensagem

Comment: Obviamente ele continua com a mesma mensagem de erro, `print` só serve para mostrar determinado valor na saída padrão. Qual foi o valor mostrado?

Comment: Pronto, sua pergunta está respondida. "Espaço" não é um número válido, como seria possível a conversão de um espaço para um número?

Answer (score 1):

Entendi! Obrigado jbueno, resolvi colocando o get() dentro da função. assim ele não pegava a Entry em branco (o espaço). Porém agora a contagem não continua, por exemplo, se eu coloco 60 na Entry, ele vai para 59 e não continua, congelando em 59. Tem ideia de como resolver?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()

def tick():
    sec = int(inicio.get())
    if sec == 0:
        time['text'] = 'TEMPO ESGOTADO'
    else:
        sec = sec - 1
        time['text'] = sec
        time.after(1000, tick)

label = Label(root, text="Quanto tempo você tem para realizar suas  tarefas?")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
inicio = Entry(root, textvariable=0)
inicio.grid(row=1, column=0)
time = Label(root, fg='green')
time.grid(row=2, column=0)
Button(root, fg='blue', text='Start', command=tick).grid(row=3, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe outra solução, caso queira fazer mais de uma contagem durante a execução do programa (na solução proposta pelo Fabiano o "Entry" será lido apenas uma vez):

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()

def tick(validador = False,sec = None):
    if validador == False:
        sec = int(inicio.get())
    if sec == 0:
        time['text'] = 'TEMPO ESGOTADO'
    else:
        sec = sec - 1
        time['text'] = sec
        time.after(1000, lambda : tick(True,sec))


label = Label(root, text="Quanto tempo você tem para realizar suas  tarefas?")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
inicio = Entry(root, textvariable=0)
inicio.grid(row=1, column=0)
time = Label(root, fg='green')
time.grid(row=2, column=0)
Button(root, fg='blue', text='Start', command=tick).grid(row=3, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Na função "after" não é possível chamar funções com parâmetros, por isso o uso do lambda que faz basicamente retornar a função "tick" com os paramêtros (essa tarefa também pode ser feita pela função partial do modulo itertools).

A variável "validador" basicamente vericifica se a função esta sendo chamada 
de modo recursivo ou atráves do click no botão, note que quando a função "tick" 
é chamada pelo click do botão ela o faz com os parametros nos valores "default", no caso
"validador" == "False". Portanto, o primeiro "if" verifica o valor de "validador" caso seja "False" captura o texto da variável "inicio".

Já a variável "sec" basicamente é usada para passar o valor do tempo para a proxima vez que a função "tick" for chamada de modo recursivo, além disso seu valor default é passado como "None" porque antes de o botão ser clicado não existe tempo algum.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: funcionou bem, obrigado! Poderia apenas explicar as mudanças (para que serve o validador; o sec=None; e as mudanças no .after, como o uso do lambda : tick(True, sec))?

Comment: Fiz uma pequena explicação, se não der para entender me avise.

Answer (score 0):

Sua variável 'sec' está sempre pegando o valor que está no input, por isso parece que não está atualizando.

Para ilustrar, iniciei a variável como global. Veja:

```
from Tkinter import*

root = Tk()

sec = None

def tick():
    global sec
    if sec == None:
        sec = int(inicio.get())
    if sec == 0:
        time['text'] = 'TEMPO ESGOTADO'
    else:
        sec = sec - 1
        time['text'] = sec
        time.after(1000, tick)

label = Label(root, text="Quanto tempo você tem para realizar suas  tarefas?")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)
inicio = Entry(root, textvariable=0)
inicio.grid(row=1, column=0)
time = Label(root, fg='green')
time.grid(row=2, column=0)
Button(root, fg='blue', text='Start', command=tick).grid(row=3, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Dessa maneira só vai ler o valor do input na primera vez